# postgresql database owner can't access database - "No relations found."

Tags: postgresql, user-permissions

I've got an user: user_x that owns a database on postgresql and does not have any ROLE attribute like (CREATE_DB, SUPERUSER,...)

This user_x can access the whole DB, create tables (on his database), select, insert and update data.

I've got this list of databases:

```
mydatabase=> \l
                                     List of databases
          Name           |  Owner   | Encoding  | Collation | Ctype |   Access privileges   
-------------------------+----------+-----------+-----------+-------+-----------------------
 postgres                | postgres | SQL_ASCII | C         | C     | 
 mydatabase              | user_x   | UTF8      | C         | C     | 
 template0               | postgres | SQL_ASCII | C         | C     | =c/postgres          +
                         |          |           |           |       | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1               | postgres | SQL_ASCII | C         | C     | =c/postgres          +
                         |          |           |           |       | postgres=CTc/postgres
 whoami                  | postgres | SQL_ASCII | C         | C     | 
(6 rows)
```

and the following roles:

```
mydatabase=> \du
                       List of roles
 Role name |            Attributes             | Member of 
-----------+-----------------------------------+-----------
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB | {}
 user_x    |                                   | {}

mydatabase=> \d
                        List of relations
 Schema |               Name                |   Type   |  Owner   
--------+-----------------------------------+----------+----------
 public | addresses                         | table    | user_x
 public | addresses_id_seq                  | sequence | user_x
 public | assignments                       | table    | user_x
 public | assignments_id_seq                | sequence | user_x

 ...
```

All right, till I dump data and restore it on another postgresql server.

After import the data with on another server (with same database name and user) and logged on psql the **\d** command reply with: **"No relations found."**

So I added **SUPERUSER** role to user_x on the imported database server and tadã user_x can see the relations and data again.

But user_x don't need to have SUPERUSER privilege to access this database.

What's wrong with this imported dump?
Does anyone now how to solve this?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Perhaps the schema permissions for the `public` schema got mangled. What is the output of `\dn+` on both sites?

The output should look like this:

```
                          List of schemas
  Name  |  Owner   |  Access privileges   |      Description       
--------+----------+----------------------+------------------------
 public | postgres | postgres=UC/postgres | standard public schema
                   : =UC/postgres           
(1 row)
```

If the `=UC/postgres` part is missing, you can restore it with

```
grant all on schema public to public;
```

Comment: Hi there A.H. ninja skills you must have. You were right! The Access privileges was null.

Comment: Ahh many thanks for those 3 hours of my life that you just gave me back with this one!

Comment: What does the `c` in the permission represent, so I can add that by itself, instead of adding all permission I don't want to be added?

Comment: @WorstForum: `c` is `CREATE`, `u` is `USAGE`. These are the only permissions supported by a schema.

Comment: I had the same problem but with RDS... so no possibility to run grant all command. Any ideas?

Comment: Actually, giving `GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public TO public` isn't such a good idea in terms of security, as it grants usage and create privileges on the public schema to all users. Maybe with `GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO user_x;` should be enough. I found a good detailed explanation of the "Access privileges" column here: https://severalnines.com/blog/postgresql-privileges-and-security-locking-down-public-schema

Answer (score 1):

## Did not find any relations.

You will also get this if your database has no tables.

```
iripmu=# select * from testtable;
 id |    Name
----+------------
  1 | Bear
  2 | Tiger
(2 rows)

iripmu=# drop table if exists testtable;
DROP TABLE
iripmu=# \dt
Did not find any relations.
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using psql 16.0, server 15.1. I renamed a connection in DataGrip and now I can't see any of the tables (even after reverting back to the previous name). Any idea how can I show the tables?

```
postgres=# \dn+
                                       List of schemas
  Name  |       Owner       |           Access privileges            |      Description       
--------+-------------------+----------------------------------------+------------------------
 public | pg_database_owner | pg_database_owner=UC/pg_database_owner+| standard public schema
        |                   | =U/pg_database_owner                   |
```