# Why can I only see postgreSQL relations or tables when I'm logged in as the postgres user?

Tags: postgresql, permissions, database-relations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [postgresql database owner can't access database - “No relations found.”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7758533/postgresql-database-owner-cant-access-database-no-relations-found)

**The core problem:** I have a **Django website** that's complaining about **relations (tables) not existing** when I connect to it *after* attempting to run a SQL script generated by `pg_dump MY_DATABASE_NAME -cOx -E UTF8 > MY_SCRIPT_NAME.sql`

**Before** running the script I'd could connect and all was right with the world.

**After** running the script I live in a world of pain that I've attempted to alleviate by examining and altering ownership of MY_DATABASE_NAME and tables using the various methods described in [Modify OWNER on all tables simultaneously in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348126/modify-owner-on-all-tables-simultaneously-in-postgresql)

It would seem that I can only see relations via `\dt` on MY_DATABASE_NAME only after having first logged in as the postgres user on my server like so: `sudo su - postgres`.

When I SSH and run `psql MY_DATABASE_NAME -U MY_NON_POSTGRES_USER` *without* switching to the postgres user, `\dt' results in a`no relations found` message.

At first I presumed permissions or ownership was the problem. I logged-in as my server's postgres user and changed owner of MY_DATABASE_NAME and all of its tables to MY_NON_POSTGRES_USER.

Same results as before. Relations show up for my postgres user, but logging in as another role results in a 'no relations found message', and my website complains that 'relation some_table doesn't exist'

Why is this happening to me?

Comment: Seems to be the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7758533

Comment: @A.H. I agree. I'm surprised that one didn't show up at the top of the list that gets auto-generated when I typed my question. I'll flag it. I'm just happy I was able to figure it out :) Thank you!

Comment: @A.H. would you mind voting to close this question. I voted to close it but it needs 4 more votes!

Comment: Okkaay, if you ask yourself - here you are.

Answer (score 5):

Wow. I really just composed a **TL;DR** description of my question and realized immediately afterwards my folly:

Although I'd connected to MY_DATABASE_NAME and given ownership to the correct user for all tables and the database, I'd forgotten to:

`REVOKE ALL ON SCHEMA public FROM MY_NON_POSTGRES_USER;`

`GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public TO MY_NON_POSTGRES_USER;`

No more pain. All is right with the world again.