# PostgreSQL - No relations found.

Tags: postgresql

I’m totally new to developer world, so I apologize if I’m not make my question clearly, please don’t be hesitate to point out if I did any wrong. Thanks.

I faced this problem on setting my PostgreSQL DB, `no relations found` when type command `timlin=# \d`.

I did try below solution to fix but it didn’t work.
[postgresql database owner can't access database - "No relations found."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7758533/postgresql-database-owner-cant-access-database-no-relations-found)

Below is my situation

```
timlin=# \dn+

                      List of schemas
  Name  | Owner  | Access privileges |      Description       
--------+--------+-------------------+————————————
 public | timlin | timlin=UC/timlin +| standard public schema
        |        | =UC/timlin        | 
(1 row)

timlin=# \l
                                    List of databases
        Name         | Owner  | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    | Access privileges  
---------------------+--------+----------+-------------+-------------+--------------------
 postgres            | timlin | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 psqlapp             | timlin | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 psqlapp_development | timlin | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 psqlapp_test        | timlin | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 psqlappdemo         | timlin | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =Tc/timlin        +
                     |        |          |             |             | timlin=CTc/timlin +
                     |        |          |             |             | psqlapp=CTc/timlin
 template0           | timlin | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/timlin         +
                     |        |          |             |             | timlin=CTc/timlin
 template1           | timlin | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/timlin         +
                     |        |          |             |             | timlin=CTc/timlin
 timlin              | timlin | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
(8 rows)

timlin=# \du
                             List of roles
 Role name |                   Attributes                   | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------+-----------
 psqlapp   |                                                | {}
 timlin    | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}
```

I check each one and couldn't find any difference between previous soultion. 
While I try

```
timlin=# \d
```

I still got the result :
    No relations found.

What do I missed ? How can I fix it ? 
Please advice and thank you all in advence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would imply that the database **timlin** does not contain any tables in the **public** schema (which is what `\d` would normally list).

It sounds like you created an empty database, e.g.:

```
createdb -h localhost -U postgres timlin
```

In which case, immediately after creation, `\d` would return:

> No relations found.

You would need to explicitly create one or more tables in order to see anything listed in the output of `\d`.

e.g. if you do the following:

```
create table foo (id serial, val text);
```

And then do a `\d`, the following output will result:

```
             List of relations
 Schema |    Name    |   Type   |  Owner   
--------+------------+----------+----------
 public | foo        | table    | postgres
 public | foo_id_seq | sequence | postgres
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Hi @khampsom, thanks for your answer, your are correct. It works after I creat a table.
Thank you !