# Amazon RDS - Postgresql database owner can't access database after DB engine upgrade

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

After upgrading from postgresql 9.6 to 10.1-R1, the user do not have access to tables.

after investigation, I found the exact same issue on that [post](http://:%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7758533/postgresql-database-owner-cant-access-database-no-relations-found/7758860#7758860)

When I look at my access privileges, it is empty:

```
\dn+
                        List of schemas
  Name  |  Owner   | Access privileges |      Description
--------+----------+-------------------+------------------------
 public | rdsadmin |                   | standard public schema
```

When it should be `postgres=UC/postgres=UC/postgres`

It was correctly set before migration

the recommendation was to run the command `grant all on schema public to <my user>;` but I don't have enough permission with RDS. Any recomendation to handle this with RDS?

Comment: Hey, i have the same issue. Can you post again the link to the aws forum? The current link is broken. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the solution from the AWS forum.

First, run

`ALTER SCHEMA PUBLIC OWNER TO <my rds_superuser>;`

Then run the grant statement after:
`grant all on schema public to <my user>;`